# Javascript event after all controls posted to the page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created a javascript that checks if the grid have no rows it will insert a cell with input button in it, the problem is that when i try to fetch the grid by document.getElementByID() the value returned is null because the controls is not yet loaded to the page. So is there an event that would interact with controls cause i don't want to invoke it from the page, i would like this to be automatically ?

Edit:
I have tried window.onload and it didn't work, the wierd thing is that when i traced it, the page load runs first and the grid gets populate then the javascript function fires.

Here is the code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

window.onload = gridAddButton();
function gridAddButton() {

    var gridTable = document.getElementById('<%=GridView_Users.ClientID%>');
    gridTableRowsLength = gridTable.rows.length;

    if (gridTableRowsLength == 0) {

        var addButton = document.createElement('input');
        addButton.id = 'tempButtonAdd';

        gridTable.rows[1].cells[4].appendChild(addButton);
    }
}
```

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_Users" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" Width="100%" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Company" HeaderText="Company" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_Edit" runat="server" 
                    onclick="LinkButton_Edit_Click">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_Delete" runat="server" 
                    onclick="LinkButton_Delete_Click">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Are you running the code after the page has loaded? Try using window.onload or other some such event.

Comment: yes i am using window.onload, and the weird is that my grid gets populated first then the javascript function is fired.

Comment: Then use another event on the grid and fire it after it's populated/loaded.

Comment: Will that work, could you explain a little more ?

Comment: What type of grid are you using ? Post your actual code...

Answer (score 0):

You should use DOM Ready event. You can use a library like jQuery to do that for you, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Here, the grid is made into DOM, so you can access it.
});
```

However, if you still have problems, then you should check other causes. For example, Microsoft ASP.NET controls tend to change the `id` attribute at runtime, so you might need use `ClientIDMode='Static'` in your page, to get sure that you can get your element using `document.getElementById();`.

Comment: Read the comments, he is already using this, the problem is he has an async call to populate the grid.

Comment: ACTUALLY, all  this code works well with document ready. Window.onload doesn't necessary mean that all DOM elements are loaded and ready for use. The question here is if jQuery is needed or a workaround method like here http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domready.shtml